# What is the correct usage of have_func when the test function needs arguments?

Tags: c, ruby, atlas, extconf.rb, mkmf

I have an `extconf.rb` with the following lines:

```
have_header("cblas.h")                 # checking for cblas.h... yes
have_func("cblas_dgemm", ["cblas.h"])  # checking for cblas_dgemm() in cblas.h... no
create_header("nmatrix_config.h")      # creating nmatrix_config.h
```

So, `cblas_dgemm` is definitely in `cblas.h`. When I look at [mkmf.log](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/5279488), I see that this check actually looks for two things:

1. a `_cblas_dgemm` symbol somewhere (?)
2. a callable `cblas_dgemm` in `cblas.h`.

Both tests are failing. I assume the former is failing because I need a `dir_config` line for `cblas`, and maybe a `have_library('cblas')`.

But I can't figure out how to make the latter test pass (see line 24 of the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mohawkjohn/5279488)). Is it possible to pass a block to `have_func` so it actually calls it with reasonable arguments? Or is there some other way to run this test? Or do I have to have the `dir_config` stuff setup properly?

Here's line 24, by the way:

```
conftest.c:7:1: error: too few arguments to function ‘cblas_dgemm’
```

And yes, of course, `cblas_dgemm` needs many arguments -- some of them matrices.

It's frustrating how little documentation there is on any of these `mkmf` functions.

Comment: Have you tried just `have_func('cblas_dgemm')`? That might just try to link something that references the `cblas_dgemm` function without involving the header at all. You'll need to figure out the appropriate `-l` switches first though.

Comment: I have, and it works in some cases, but the lack of documentation makes it almost impossible to predict *when* it will happen.

Comment: How come no one has bothered to rewrite `mkmf`? It seems like a good candidate for a rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like `have_func` is pretty poorly documented, but upon some digging I found something that might help:

```
[25] pry(main)> have_func("clapack_dgetrf", "/usr/local/atlas/include/clapack.h")
checking for clapack_dgetrf() in /usr/local/atlas/include/clapack.h... no
=> false
[26] pry(main)> have_func("int clapack_dgetrf", "/usr/local/atlas/include/clapack.h")
checking for int clapack_dgetrf() in /usr/local/atlas/include/clapack.h... yes
=> true
```

So, essentially it looks like you need to include at least the return type to get `have_func` to work properly. Can you verify that this works on your machine?

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

In `mkmf.rb` of `ruby 1.9.3p392`, The latter test is executed only if the former fails. When the former passes, `have_func` successes. So you don't have to make the latter pass. Refer to `try_func` in `mkmf.rb` for more details.

Just for information, in [`mkmf.rb` on 2013-04-13 11:00:25](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/b35529bb4e9b7c1f328e4515106b4b96aec94167/lib/mkmf.rb#L721), it seems you can give arguments like this: `have_func("some_func(some_arg, another_arg)", ["foo.h"])`.